# J2ME Byte Array ZIP Compression

Tags: java-me, compression, zip, arrays

Is there some library or built-in funcionality in J2ME to compress a byte array trough ZIP?

I'd like to do something like this:

byte[] data;
byte[] compressed = ZIPLibrary.compress(data);

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me/